# SSRS 2008: How to generate multiple reports immediately?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Im building a site which brings up SSRS reports by opening new windows with the report url and report parameters. I can currenlty open a window for each report they want to run.

However, they also want the option to save the reports to a file share or Sharepoint of their choice, instead of having a bunch of browser window pop-ups for each report.

I understand I can use SSRS web services to setup a schedule (to run in a couple minutes from the time of request) which can save those files to a file share (or Sharepoint) but that seems like a hack to get a one time generating of reports onto a file share or sharepoint.

Is there any other way to instantly generate a bunch of reports, one time, immediately, without having to set them up on a scheduler that is set to run a couple minutes from the time they set it up?

Answer (score 0):

"Note, they DO NOT want one report that has all the reports in it, these are seperate reports that are already built, and they want one file/window per report."

Not sure what you want when you say you want them all at once but one file window/per report?  What presentation layer is showing this?  You can make three seperate web calls at the same time to the webservice instead of the hosting site:

h ttp://(servername)/(ReporstServer)/PathtoReport1

h ttp://(servername)/(ReporstServer)/PathtoReport2

h ttp://(servername)/(ReporstServer)/PathtoReport3

instead of

h ttp://(servername)/(Reports)

If you just mean 'separate pages' on an Excel workbook you can do that with one report nesting other sub reports.  You can build a master report that has rectangle objects that define pages as their properties and place a sub report in each of these rectangles.

Or you could make an html page that references the calls three seperate times in a 'form' object of the HTML doing a 'post' command.

< Form id="SSRSRender" action="http://(servername)/(reportServer)/(report) method="post" target="self">

"However, they also want the option to save the reports to a file share or Sharepoint of their choice, instead of having a bunch of browser window pop-ups for each report.

I understand I can use SSRS web services to setup a schedule (to run in a couple minutes from the time of request) which can save those files to a file share (or Sharepoint) but that seems like a hack to get a one time generating of reports onto a file share or sharepoint."

That's not a hack, that is the preferred method of saving a file is using the built in web service scheduler.   Once a report is hosted (on a server hosting the SSRS) it can have configs set for SMTP send outs, file saves, and snapshots made.

If that is not enough you can create your own proxy classes if you want in C# or VB.NET and try to build your own front end talking to SSRS through SOAP requests to the Web Service.

Comment: I am asking if there is an alternative to scheduling if i want to save reports to a remote location, your answer is no, if i understand correclty

Comment: You can choose a 'subscription' to 'Save' reports instead of email them as well.  In fact if you don't have an SMTP server defined in your SSRS admin config it will default to this.  You just need to ensure the SSRS service account has access to the path you specify.  Hover over a report and click the arrow box drop down to select 'Subscribe'.  This opens up window.  Change combox box from 'Choose method of delivery' to 'Windows File Share'.  You now have options to save the report on a time schedule in formats chosen to a particular path.